# Fragment leaks when exit form activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I cannot figure out how to plug the leakage in my PlabackActivity

here is important part of PlaybackActivity:

```
    class PlaybackActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private var playbackFragment: PlaybackFragment? = null


    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.playback_activity)

        val f = playbackFragment
            ?: run {
                val fragment = PlaybackFragment.newInstance()
                playbackFragment = fragment
                fragment
            }

        replacePlaybackFragment(f)

    }


    private fun replacePlaybackFragment(fragment: BasePlaybackFragment) {

        val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.playbackFragmentContainer, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName )
        ft.addToBackStack(null)
        ft.commit()
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        Timber.d("onDestroy()")
        playbackFragment = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}

ExoPlayerAdapter:

    class ExoPlayerAdapter(val context: Context) {

    var callback: ExoPlayerAdapterCallback? = null

    private val player: SimpleExoPlayer

    private val runnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            callback?.onCurrentPositionChanged(this@ExoPlayerAdapter)
            callback?.onBufferedPositionChanged(this@ExoPlayerAdapter)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }
    }
    private val handler = Handler()
    private var initialized = false

    private var mediaSourceUri: Uri? = null
    private var mediaSourceDrmUri: Uri? = null

    private var hasDisplay: Boolean = false
    private var bufferingStart: Boolean = false

    @C.StreamType
    var audioStreamType: Int = 0

    init {
        player = initExo2()

        player.addAnalyticsListener(object : AnalyticsListener {
            override fun onDownstreamFormatChanged(eventTime: AnalyticsListener.EventTime?, mediaLoadData: MediaSourceEventListener.MediaLoadData?) {
                mediaLoadData?.trackFormat
            }
        })
    }

    private fun initExo2(): SimpleExoPlayer {

        val defaultDrmSessionManager = DefaultDrmSessionManager<FrameworkMediaCrypto>(
            C.WIDEVINE_UUID,
            LicenceExoMediaDrm(),
            HttpMediaDrmCallback(),
            HashMap()
        )

        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            context,
            DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
            DefaultTrackSelector(AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()),
            DefaultLoadControl
                .Builder()
                .setAllocator(DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE * 512))
                .createDefaultLoadControl(),
            defaultDrmSessionManager
        )

        return exoPlayer
    }

    fun reset() {
        changeToUninitialized()
        player.stop()
    }

    private fun changeToUninitialized() {
        if (initialized) {
            initialized = false
            if (hasDisplay) {
                callback?.onPreparedStateChanged(this)
                onPreparedStateChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    fun release() {
        changeToUninitialized()
        hasDisplay = false
        player.release()
    }

    fun onDetachedFromHost() {
        reset()
        release()
    }
    internal fun setDisplay(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder?) {
        val hadDisplay = hasDisplay
        hasDisplay = surfaceHolder != null

        if (hadDisplay == hasDisplay) {
            return
        }

        player.setVideoSurfaceHolder(surfaceHolder)
        if (hasDisplay) {
            if (initialized) {
                callback?.onPreparedStateChanged(this)
                onPreparedStateChanged()
            }
        } else {
            if (initialized) {
                callback?.onPreparedStateChanged(this)
                onPreparedStateChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    fun setProgressUpdatingEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
        if (!enabled) {
            return
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
    }

    fun setDataSource(mediaSourceUri: Uri?, drmUri: Uri): Boolean {

        Timber.d("setDataSource uri=$mediaSourceUri drm=$drmUri")
        if (if (this.mediaSourceUri != null) this.mediaSourceUri == mediaSourceUri else mediaSourceUri == null) {
            return false
        }
        this.mediaSourceUri = mediaSourceUri
        this.mediaSourceDrmUri = drmUri

        prepareMediaForPlaying()
        return true
    }

    private fun onCreateMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource {
        Timber.d("onCreateMediaSource() $uri")
        val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, "ExoPlayerAdapter")
        val defaultDataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, userAgent)
        return createDashSource(uri, defaultDataSourceFactory)

    }

    private fun createDashSource(url: Uri, dataSourceFactory: DefaultDataSourceFactory): DashMediaSource {
        return DashMediaSource.Factory(
            DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory),
            dataSourceFactory
        )
            .setManifestParser(object : DashManifestParser() {})
            .setLoadErrorHandlingPolicy(AmbLoadErrorHandlingPolicy())
            .createMediaSource(url)
    }

    private fun prepareMediaForPlaying() {
        reset()
        if (mediaSourceUri != null) {
            val mediaSource = onCreateMediaSource(mediaSourceUri)
            player.prepare(mediaSource, true, true)
        } else {
            return
        }

        notifyBufferingStartEnd()
        callback?.onPlayStateChanged(this@ExoPlayerAdapter)

        //after reload player with new live stream the progress bar are not updated
        //so enable updating is needed.
        setProgressUpdatingEnabled(true)
    }

    var playWhenPreparedCallback: () -> Unit = {}

    fun playWhenPrepared() {
        if (isPrepared()) {
            play()
        } else {
            playWhenPreparedCallback = { play() }
        }
    }

    private fun onPreparedStateChanged() {
        if (isPrepared()) {
            playWhenPreparedCallback()
            playWhenPreparedCallback = {}
        }
    }
    fun play() {
        player.playWhenReady = true
    }
    }
```

And here is LeakCanary report:

```
    HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
====================================
2 APPLICATION LEAKS

References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.

232640 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: b79dd5a31e7bdd68a5fe42fe4139e4a5625ce7
┬───
│ GC Root: Input or output parameters in native code
│
├─ android.os.MessageQueue instance
│    Leaking: NO (MessageQueue#mQuitting is false)
│    ↓ MessageQueue.mMessages
│                   ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.os.Message instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ Message.callback
│              ~~~~~~~~
├─ tvapp.player.exo2.ExoPlayerAdapter$runnable$1 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous class implementing java.lang.Runnable
│    ↓ ExoPlayerAdapter$runnable$1.this$0
│                                  ~~~~~~
├─ tvapp.player.exo2.ExoPlayerAdapter instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ExoPlayerAdapter.context
│                       ~~~~~~~
╰→ tvapp.player.PlaybackActivity instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because tvapp.player.PlaybackActivity received Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
​     key = cdf5901a-cd24-49ba-b61f-d8d36e092dfa
​     watchDurationMillis = 15583
​     retainedDurationMillis = 10583

10621 bytes retained by leaking objects
Signature: 21cac0892d97b1f1d0dd68f578a458aa63ddc4f
┬───
│ GC Root: Input or output parameters in native code
│
├─ android.os.MessageQueue instance
│    Leaking: NO (MessageQueue#mQuitting is false)
│    ↓ MessageQueue.mMessages
│                   ~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.os.Message instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ Message.callback
│              ~~~~~~~~
├─ tvapp.player.exo2.ExoPlayerAdapter$runnable$1 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous class implementing java.lang.Runnable
│    ↓ ExoPlayerAdapter$runnable$1.this$0
│                                  ~~~~~~
├─ tvapp.player.exo2.ExoPlayerAdapter instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ExoPlayerAdapter.callback
│                       ~~~~~~~~
├─ tvapp.player.PlaybackFragment$setupUi$4 instance
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    Anonymous subclass of tvapp.player.exo2.ExoPlayerAdapterCallback
│    ↓ PlaybackFragment$setupUi$4.this$0
│                                    ~~~~~~
╰→ tvapp.player.PlaybackFragment instance
​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because tvapp.player.PlaybackFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
​     key = e4624d0a-b31a-4813-969b-08345bff6423
​     watchDurationMillis = 15489
​     retainedDurationMillis = 10488
​     key = eb37451d-0ff6-45be-ad7b-7120f391f03d
​     retainedDurationMillis = 10489
```

Comment: ExoPlayerAdapter is your class or any library class?

Comment: ExoPlayerAdapter  is my class

Comment: Post code of that class

Comment: handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) 
call when fragment destroying.

Comment: hey did you manage to solve this issue.. cause i am facing this same issue

Answer (score 0):

`ExoPlayerAdapter` has a `context` field which is the activity instance, it has a `callback` field which is an inner class of `PlaybackFragment`, and it continuously posts a `runnable` to the main thread which holds on to the `ExoPlayerAdapter` instance.

On Android, objects have a lifecycle. Activities are created then destroyed, same for Fragments. You have to decide what the lifecycle of `ExoPlayerAdapter` should be, and write your code accordingly.

- `PlaybackFragment` should clear the `ExoPlayerAdapter` callback in `Fragment.onDestroy()`
- If `ExoPlayerAdapter` should live longer than the activity instance, then you should pass it an application context instead of the activity context. If it should live as long as the activity instance, then you should call `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` when the activity is destroyed.